# Print server for Xerox 5016

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, print-server

What print server is compatible with [Xerox WorkCentre 5016](http://www.office.xerox.com/multifunction-printer/multifunction-under-30ppm/workcentre-5016/enae.html) ?

So far I found an Edimax PS-1206U but this Xerox model is not listed as supported.

Printing is the most important thing that I want to achieve from this printer and
second scanning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a shopping question per se so I will suggest a [Startech USB Print Server](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Print/10-100-Mbps-USB-Print-Server~PM1115U)  It is economical and has worked with a number of HP, Lexmark and Epson printers. [HP](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF02a/18972-18972-236253.html?dnr=1) has several as well.